# Convert callback function from C++ to VB.Net

Tags: c++, vb.net, function, callback, pinvoke

I'm trying to convert C++ API to VB.Net, but this function is too hard and i don't know how make it work.

Here is the API doc for this function:

---

```
void RemoteDllSetReceiver(void *inst, on_received_buffer_t received_buf_cb);
```

Sets a callback function to receive notifications from the DLL. The prototype of the callback is:

```
typedef bool (*on_received_buffer_t)(void* inst, const unsigned char *buffer, unsigned int size);
```

Where

- inst is the pointer originally passed to RemoteDllSetReceiver
- buffer & size contain the notification text as defined in the Remote Protocol.

Note: notifications may arrive in different threads (e.g. network, timer, audio).

---

I can't imagine what i mus do with on_received_buffer_t, must it be a delegate? Like you can read, this functions returns notifications from the DLL like connection status, user id...

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `on_received_buffer_t` is a pointer to a callback function with prototype as you've shown. I'm unfamiliar with VB.NET but yes, probably it must be a `delegate` and probably `<UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)> (which I just copied and pasted from [here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-2339674.php)). It might help to mention what API it is, and perhaps give example of the code that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I must add that i'm using Visual Studio 2008 and Compact Framework 3.5. My current work is:

P/Invoke Function:

```
Private Declare Function RemoteDllSetReceiver Lib "remote_dll.dll" (ByVal inst As IntPtr, ByVal received_buf_cb As on_received_buffer_t) As Integer
```

Delegate for received_buffer_t

```
Public Delegate Function on_received_buffer_t(ByVal inst As IntPtr, ByVal buffer() As Byte, ByVal size As Long) As Boolean
```

And I call it in my code:

```
RemoteDllSetReceiver(IntPtr.Zero, AddressOf ReceiveMessage)
```

ReceiveMessage Function:

```
Public Shared Function ReceiveMessage(ByVal inst As IntPtr, ByVal buffer() As Byte, ByVal size As Long) As Boolean

    MsgBox(buffer.ToString())

End Function
```

Thanks

Comment: This should be a comment or edit to your question, not an answer.

Comment: The call in the code seems to work, it doesn´t throw exception, but when the API try to return a notification, the program suddenly exit without showing errors or exceptions. So i can't debug it and see what happend.

I think the declaration of the delegate is incorrect, or maybe how i send the delegate to the P/Invoke function (AddressOf).